# ¿Qué es ":-!!" en C?

Tags: linux, c

> Pregunta original: [What is “:-!!” in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229601/what-is-in-c-code) de [chmurli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/883147/chmurli)

Me encontré con este extraño código macro en /usr/include/linux/kernel.h:

```
/* Force a compilation error if condition is true, but also produce a
result (of value 0 and type size_t), so the expression can be used
e.g. in a structure initializer (or where-ever else comma expressions
aren't permitted). */
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_NULL(e) ((void *)sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
```

¿Qué hace `:-!!` ?

Answer (score 9):

De la misma pregunta que haces referencia se dice que (por lo tanto, solo traduciré partes de las respuestas que en la pregunta existen):

El  simbolo `:` es un campo de bits . En cuanto a la doble exclamación `!!` , es una doble negación y así devuelve `0` para FALSE y `1` para TRUE. Y el guión `-` es un signo menos, es decir, la negación aritmética.

Parámetros/valores de la pregunta:

- `(e)`: devuelve la expresión `e`.
- `!!(e)`:Doble negación: devuelve `0` si `e == 0`; de lo contrario retorna `1`.
- `-!!( e)`: Negación numerica: `0` si `e == 0`; de lo contrario retorna `-1`.
- `struct {int : - !! ( 0 ) ;} -> struct {int : 0 ; }`: Si este valor es un cero, entonces se declara una estructura con un campo de bits entero. Todo está bien y se sigue el proceso de manera normal.
- `struct { int : - !! ( 1 ); } -> struct { int : -1 ; }`: de lo contrario , si no es cero, entonces será un número negativo. Declarando cualquier campo de bits con un valor negativo que es un error de compilación.